# Как подключить файл для чтения через консоль?

Tags: c#, .net

Как подключить файл для чтения через консоль, чтобы не в коде передавать адрес файла

```
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
```

А писать адрес в консоли, чтобы можно было подключать разные файлы?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` пробовали?

Comment: вы можете перенаправить ввод/вывод при запуске консольного приложения, например `myapp.exe << in.txt >> out.txt`

Comment: Метод Main может принимать массив аргументов static void Main(string[] args). Передавайте первым аргументом адрес, получиться тогда так: StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(args[0])

Comment: @tym32167 Если я не ошибаюсь, операторы сдвига в [tag:c#] не могут применять для записи/чтения в файл. Да и на `in.txt`, `out.txt` компилятор явно ругаться будет.

Comment: @Anamnian я привел пример консольной команды, компилятор тут не при чем

Comment: @Anamnian там даже не по 2 скобки, а по одной ) Типа `myfile.exe < inp.txt > out.txt` - и все чтения консоли будут читать из inp.txt, а все записи писать в out.txt

Comment: @tym32167 Я просто думал что вы перепутали с C++. Приношу извинения.

Comment: @Anamnian без проблем :)

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант 1.** Пользователь вводит путь по время выполнения программы.

При помощи [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) можно получить строку, которую ввёл пользователь.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Filename path: ");
    string filename = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"\nPath -> {filename}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вариант 2.** Использование [аргументов командной строки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments).

В функции `Main()` есть массив аргументов, как параметр. Данные туда можно передать при запуске вашего приложения через командную строку, например:

`myApp.exe param1 param2 param3` - .NET Framework

или

`dotnet myApp.dll param1 param2 param3` - .NET Core

Cкриншот ниже для `.NET Core`, но суть не меняется.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        string filename = args[0];    
        Console.WriteLine($"Filename path: {filename}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]